# How to workaround git stopping on rejected tags

Tags: git

I'm using a repository which has some tags moving around (bad idea, but let's assume this can't be changed). Specifically each tested deployment moves tag called `green`.

This causes issues with git `2.21.0`, where each `pull` does the fetch step successfully, but doesn't actually change the checked out state, because:

```
 ! [rejected]                green -> green  (would clobber existing tag)
```

If I remove the tag manually, the pull works, but after a few hours, I'm left with a rejected tag again.

Can I configure git to accept tag clobbering by default? Or filter this specific tag somehow. (I don't care if it's not available locally)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I configure git to accept tag clobbering by default?

Yes.  Using `git fetch --tags` might do it, in which case configuring `tagOpt` will work.  If that fails, an explicit `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` refspec, either on the command line or in the `fetch =` setting for the given remote, will definitely do the job.